# How to get Doctrine ORM instance in Symfony2 console application?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, console-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i inject dependencies to Symfony Console commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597912/how-can-i-inject-dependencies-to-symfony-console-commands)

I want to make console application, which changes some records from the database (using Cron, every hour). How to get Doctrine ORM instance here?

In casual controller, I do this:

```
$this->getDoctrine();
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you extend from `ContainerAwareCommand` you should be able to get your service

```
$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597912/how-can-i-inject-dependencies-to-symfony-console-commands) is similar question

Comment: Thanks ;) I search in `Symfony\Component\Console` namespace, but I haven't noticed there's `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console` and `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command` also.

Comment: Where exactly is the 'getContainer' method defined? I can't find it on the ContainterAwareCommand..

Comment: @Luke AFAIK this answer was related to `2.0` version. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm on 2.3. There seem to be a lot of posts on SO in regards to this and none of it seems to work. In the context of 2.3, how to you get a reference to the container? I assume you need to bootstrap a Kernel first which isn't standard procedure in a console app?

Comment: @Luke could you post a link to your code?

Comment: This works in Symfony 3.